# How can I interrupt a sub-command inside a pod?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, podman, sigterm

My container command consists of multiple *sub-commands*. The `yaml` file looks like this (there is only *one container* in the pod):

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
        name: t-j
        namespace: tom # job and pvc should be in the same namespace
spec:
        template:
                metadata:
                        labels:
                                app: test-job
                spec:
                        containers:
                        - name: test-job
                          image: <URL>/tom/test:v001
                          command: ["bash", "-c", "tail /proc/cpuinfo -n 28 &>> job.log; python3 setup_util_cpp.py build_ext --inplace &>> job.log; python3 script_01.py &>> job.log; python3 script_02.py &>> job.log; echo '--------------Purpose: test ----------------' &>> job.    log; mkdir result ; mv *.csv result; mv job.log result; tar -cjf result.bz2 result/ ; aws s3 cp --endpoint http://<another URL> /result.bz2  s3://mybucket01/ --no-progress --only-show-errors"]
                          resources:
                                <some other specifications>
```

Sub-command `python3 script_01.py` has been running for days. I don't need results from this script and I'd like other sub-commands run as planned. Is it possible that I can kill the current sub-command **without terminating the whole flow**?

I tried `docker kill --signal='SIGTERM' test-job`, but got `Error: no container with name or ID "test-job" found: no such container`.

`docker container ls` returned empty.

`kubectl get pods` returned `t-j-abcde`, and `docker kill --signal='SIGTERM' t-j-abcde` did not work either.

The image is based on `Ubuntu 22.04`, docker is `podman 4.6.1`

Comment: It seems you're confusing pod and container a little here. A pod is what's orchestrated by Kubernetes and can consist of one or more containers. If you'd like to interact with the pod, use `kubectl`.

Comment: @RickRackow I'm new to k8s. I guess I need to send a `SIGTERM` signal to the container. If so, the command I should use is somehow like `docker kill --signal='SIGTERM' t-j-abcde:test-job`. But I don't know how to address *a container inside a pod*. And I did not specify port in the YAML file.

Comment: Can you split this task into multiple Jobs?  You'd need some sort of program that used the Kubernetes API to monitor each Job for completion and created the next one.  Myself I might use the _operator pattern_ with a Go-based controller, but there are other choices.

Comment: If you're running the application in Kubernetes, you probably can't use `docker` commands around it at all – I wouldn't expect you to normally have login access to the Node that's running the Pod.

Comment: @DavidMaze How can I split the task into multiple jobs? Do you mean that I should create multiple containers in the above `yaml` file and have each job inside a container? Or do I use a nested array for the field `command` to define multiple jobs?

Comment: Literally multiple Job objects; each with only one container, and one command, but the first runs only `script_01.py` and so on.  The question is what needs to be persisted or shared between these various scripts, and how much they depend on being run strictly in order.

Comment: @DavidMaze In the setting *multiple job objs, each with single container*,  I assume they run in a serialized pattern, is job 2 able to access files generated from job 1? I heard that containers communicate via port, which requires job 1 and job 2 are simultaneously alive. [This container lifecycle][https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/] looks complicated I'm not sure wheter the system or the user should maintain previous container(s) alive.

Comment: Each container has its own temporary filesystem, and you'd need to arrange for the jobs' results to be stored somewhere persistent.  (...which is probably a good idea in any case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna kill a process in container, you should try these command:

```
1. kubectl exec -it -n $NAMESPACE $POD_NAME -- ps -ef # find PID
2. kubectl exec -it -n $NAMESPACE $POD_NAME -- kill $PID # kill it
```

But above operations will lead **pod restart**, then script_01.py will run again :)
Then you may want to modify spec.containers.command directly, it will also lead **pod restart**.
As all I know, the **only way** to manage **dynamic process** `python3 script_01.py` is use **[sidecar](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/08/25/native-sidecar-containers/)** container. And you show config [sharedProcessNamespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/). Attentation, **sidecar** also be implemented by **[openkruise-sidecarset](https://openkruise.io/docs/user-manuals/sidecarset/)**